# Refer to a loop variable in an argument

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a script (myscript.sh) loop that `grep`s some strings in many different files, stores them in a new file, and then `cat`s the content of this file to the terminal:

```
for i in {1..201..5}; do
        grep "Pitch" filename-$i.log | cut -d" " -f25
done > pitch.txt
echo "========Pitch==========="
cat pitch.txt
```

Here's what I'd like to do instead from the command line:

```
./myscript.sh filename-$i.log
```

This then runs myscript.sh, looping over the variable `i` that I refer to in the argument to myscript.sh.

I hope I have explained my goal here properly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to pass the base part of thew different filenames as the first parameter to your script, change the loop to:

```
for i in {1..201..5}; do
        grep "Pitch" "${1}-${i}" | cut -d" " -f25
done > pitch.txt
```

(assuming the dash is always there, and not passed as part of the parameter, and the variable part of the filenames is always at the end)

Comment: The variable part is actually not at the end, but just before the file extension. Like this: filename-1.log. I updated the question to make it clearer what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax:

```
for ((i=0; i<=$1; i=(($i + 5)) ))
        grep "Pitch" filename-$i | cut -d" " -f25
done > pitch.txt
echo "========Pitch==========="
cat pitch.txt
```

Comment: `for (( i=0; i<=$1; i+=5 ))`... But it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear what you are after, but from what I get is that you have 6 directories but each directory has files named in a similar fashion of having numbers at their end. Then you could do this like this:

```
for arg
do
   for i in {1..201..5}; do
      grep "Pitch" "$arg-$i" | cut -d" " -f25
   done > $arg/pitch.txt
   echo "========Pitch==========="
   cat $arg/pitch.txt
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This `bash` function should work:

```
foo() {
    searchstring="$1"
    shift 1
    echo "========${searchstring}===========" ; 
    grep --no-filename "${searchstring}" "$@" | \
    cut -d" " -f25 | tee "${searchstring,,}".txt 
    }
```

Invoke like so:

```
foo Pitch filename-{1..201..5}
```

---

How it works.  Since `grep` allows multiple file names from the command line, and `bash` allows prefixing a string to code like `{1..10}`, there's no need to pass file names one a time through a `for` loop.  The `cat` and `>` can both be replaced by a single `tee`.

The first argument of `foo` is the search string, (e.g. "*Match*"), which the shell sets to "*$1*" -- that gets moved to a temporary variable `$searchstring`, then "*Match*" is removed with `shift 1`, so that "*$@*" contains only the filenames.